# Error connecting the redis, in app server, with django

Tags: django, redis

[after removing the try except block from the code I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmGlS.png)

[the postman screenshot of getting the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVolR.png)

> I am trying to connect the redis ,in app server,with django. While
>   checking the api in postman I am getting an error saying the output
>   variable is referenced before assignment. But the api works good for
>   the redis that I have downloaded in my local and I am getting the
>   output as expected. I think I have went wrong while giving the
>   credentials in the settings.py file. I would like someone to help me
>   to put out this error. I have attached the redis cache credentials
>   below,

```
CACHES = {
        "default" : {
            "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
            "LOCATION": "redis:// 3.233.27.21:6379/1",
            "TIMEOUT": 86400 ,
            "OPTION": {            
                "PASSWORD": "XXXXXXX", 
                "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            },
            "KEY_PREFIX": "XXXXXX"
        }
    }
```

> The function,
>   views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.db import connection
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.status import (
    HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
    HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
    HTTP_200_OK
)
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
import json
import pandas as pd
from django.http import JsonResponse
@api_view(['POST'])
def cost_trend(request):

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        try:
            body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
            body_data = json.loads(body_unicode)
            year = body_data.get("year")
            employer = body_data.get("employer")           
            if employer != None and year != None:
                result = []          
                if 'cost_trend' in cache:#checking whether the key is in cache
                    results = cache.get('cost_trend')
                    for r in results:
                            if r['egnid'] == employer and r['dt'] == int(year):
                                result.append(r)
                    df  = pd.DataFrame(result,columns = ['paid_amt','month']) 
                    df = json.loads(df.to_json(orient = 'records'))#making the filtered data as json
                    value = 0
                    for i in df:
                        value = value + i['paid_amt']
                        i['paid_amt'] = value

                else:#if not, the data is fetched from database and stored in cache   
                    sql_query = """select json_agg(amt)
                             from
                            (select json_build_object('paid_amt',round(sum(paid_amt))::int,'month',
                            TO_CHAR(svc_from_date,'MON YYYY'),'egnid',eg_nid,'dt',extract(year from svc_from_date)) amt
                            from application.ckd_details
                            where left(paid_amt::text,1) != '-'
                            group by TO_CHAR(svc_from_date,'MON YYYY') ,eg_nid,extract(year from svc_from_date)
                            order by to_date(TO_CHAR(svc_from_date,'MON YYYY'),'MON YYYY'))a;"""

                    cursor.execute(sql_query)
                    results = cursor.fetchone()[0] 
                    connection.commit()
                    cache.set('cost_trend',results)
                    for r in results:
                        if r['egnid'] == employer and r['dt'] == int(year):
                            result.append(r)
                    df  = pd.DataFrame(result,columns = ['paid_amt','month']) 
                    df = json.loads(df.to_json(orient = 'records'))
                    value = 0
                    for i in df:
                        value = value + i['paid_amt']
                        i['paid_amt'] = value

            else:
                df = "Invalid input type"
            connection.close()    
        except:
            print("Error")
            connection.close()
    return Response(df)
```

> Thank you in advance.

Comment: "output variable is referenced before assignment", can you share your view in which you are getting that error?

Comment: Please visit the link that is given above the description,I have added the image of postman, where I got the error

Comment: Even I have the doubt, as redis is downloaded in apps server do I have to use unix domain socket

Comment: i will suggest you to add that view and error traceback. That image is not helping.

Comment: Find the function attchement below the cache credentials

Comment: looks like while executing there is some exception, that's why it is going to except block, try to define `df =  {'error': True}` in your except block and check if you are getting the same error.

Comment: {
    "error": true
}

Comment: After editing the code as u instructed , i got the output that i have commented above

Comment: it means that there is some exception in your code, remove that `try-except` block from your code so that you can debug.

Comment: I tried removing and I am getting authentication error, though i did'nt use any authentication in my application

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the error above along with the code

Comment: "Redis AuthenticationError: Authentication required". This is what precisely the error says as I gone through the error completely

Comment: so you need to fix that error first. something is wrong in your redis configuration. try to remove space between `//` and `3.233.27.21` from your redis location `redis:// 3.233.27.21:6379/1`.

Comment: Thank you . I solved the error.